# my HTC doesn't have lollipop, can you explain

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Lollipop is not on my HTC and I do not know why, lollipop is 5.etc but my htc is on 3.etc

Comment: Android 3.x is Honeycomb and is exclusive for Android tablet. Are you sure it's the Android version, not the Sense version? Anyway, old devices won't get official update support by vendor since it's considered as wasting time and resource to provide update for all their old devices; not every device will get new Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Which HTC model is it?

Android 5.0 has not been rolled out across all devices yet. Try undergoing a software update from the settings menu to update to a newer version of Android.

Alternatively, if you take a look on the XDA Developer Forums (http://www.xda-developers.com/), you can look for an Android Lollipop 5.0 custom ROM specifically for your device. You can then flash your device and utilise the new features provided in Lollipop.

**N.B.** Before flashing a new custom ROM, make sure you have a rooted device and an active recovery bootloader such as CWM (https://www.clockworkmod.com/) in case something goes wrong.